# I have encoded bootstrap grid system as it has to be but when I make screen smaller everything goes wrong?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am just new for bootstrap.
I have downloaded and enqueued in my function.php now when I write this code:

```
<section class="container" id="repair">

<div class="row">

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Reparatie</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Grote beurt</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Kleine beurt</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Olie verversen</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Wintercheck</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
<h5>Zomercheck</h5>
</article>

</div>


</section>
```

and when I go to my website url:http://webdesignleren.net/reparatie-ondehoud/

I see in large screen the 6 columns but when I beginto make the screen smaller then I don't see md-4  the 3 columns .  everything is going wrong after making the screen smaller .
how it comes that ,what I do wrong do I have to write media queries ?
but I think in first place it has to be md-4 format when I make the screen smaller because I worked also with foundation grid system.
thanks
johannes

Comment: I think you missed the class for extra small (mobile) screens which is `col-xs-*`. Is that what's holding you?

Comment: you are using foundation framework and bootstrap framework on your website!?

Comment: yes I saw that  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use unwanted cols. Try this code.

```
<section class="container" id="repair">

<div class="row">

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Reparatie</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Grote beurt</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Kleine beurt</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Olie verversen</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Wintercheck</h5>
</article>

<article class="col-md-6">
<h5>Zomercheck</h5>
</article>

</div>


</section>
```